# What is the difference between the following two tests: w.isupper () and not w.islower ()?

Tags: python

It's a question at the crossroads between computing and set theory

I just immersed myself in the Python documentation to answer this question

> Let say $w$ is a string. What is the difference between the following two tests: `w.isupper ()` and `not w.islower ()`

For me, the difference is that, in mathematical terms, `w.isupper ()` means
$$∀x ∈ w, x∈ Upper$$

`not w.islower ()` means

$$∃ x ∈ w, x ∉ Lower$$

I do not know if it is enough for everyone to say that it is different, it is [Set theory](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teor%C3%ADa_de_untos) and, sometimes, I really need time to understand it.
Also, there may be other computational or python reasons that I do not know

This question is from chapter 1 of Natural Language Processing with Python

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `w` is a string (or a byte array or something similar), the docs say following:

> [str.isupper()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=isupper#str.isupper)
>
> Return true if all cased characters in the string are uppercase and there is at least one cased character, false otherwise.

And

> [str.islower()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=islower#str.islower)
>
> Return true if all cased characters in the string are lowercase and there is at least one cased character, false otherwise.

So `w.isupper()` checks whether *all* characters are in uppercase, while `w.islower` checks whether *all* characters are in lowercase. Therefore `not w.islower()` checks whether there is at least one uppercase character.

This is exactly what you've guessed in your post.

Comment: Yes but what about `w = a?b`

Comment: What is `a?b`? Consider posting further questions as seperate posts.

Comment: `a?b` It's a string, it's still the same question

Comment: @Marine1: `a?b` may be Python syntax for some string, but we're not Python experts enough to know which string that is ...

Comment: @Marine1 if `w = a?b` and `a?b` is a string, then so is `w`, and the answer is also the same.